# Error when calling a class that uses a folder within the same directory as the class, but is applied within a file that runs in another directory

Tags: python, class, directory

I am having some trouble using a class I have created which includes a function that calls a folder of geojson files. The folder lives in the same directory as the .py file with the class and it is very important that I do not provide the full path for this folder.

If I do provide the full path, the function works perfectly. However, this is a shared folder with other users and for this reason, we need to keep the folder path like `'./geo_first_division'`.

In more detail, I provide a scheme of the folders below and the folder named as "classes_folder" is the shared one. The file "class_geo.py" has a function within, say `fun1()`, which needs the content of the folder "geo_first_division".

The "app.py" is within the "app_folder" and although it works perfectly for all the functions within the class, it will break for the `fun1()` giving an error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './geojson_first_division'`.

There must be something that I do not see clearly here and I would appreciate some help.

[image]

Comment: ANSWERING QUESTION -wrongly connected as dupl: I included in my class before any def the following: dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), which actually gives the possibility to return the directory path of the current file. Within the def "fun1()", I used the following as folder_path: folder_path = f'''{self.dir_path}/geo_first_division'''. This way, the class can live in a different directory from the directory that a .py file lives with the latter calling the class. It also gives the possibility to other users to use it without making any changes in the code.

Comment: The second answer in the linked solution provides an approach similar to yours using `pathlib`. The question is correctly marked as a duplicate.